# Algebraic identity involving partitions of indexes

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Consider the polynomial $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n+y)^{n-1}$ and its set of indexes $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. For a subset $I \subset [n]$ denote by $x_I$ the sum $\sum_{i \in I}x_i$ and by $|I|$ its cardinality. Denote by $L=\{L_\alpha \}$ a partition of set $[n]$ ($[n]=\amalg_\alpha L_\alpha$) and by $|L|$ its cardinality - number of non-empty subsets it divides $[n]$ into. Prove that:

$$(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n+y)^{n-1}=\sum_L \left(y^{|L|-1}\times \prod_\alpha
x_{L_\alpha}^{|L_\alpha|-1}\right)$$

where the sum is taken over all partitions $L$ of the set $[n]$.

I know this identity is true but I don't know whether it's a well-known result that has a simple direct proof.

Comment: How do you know it is true?

Comment: It follows from calculation of some double Hurwitz numbers in two different ways. You can also run a program to check it is true for a few first n.